Three equations three unknowns
I have the following set of equations with a,b,c being real numbers
$$a^2 (b+c)= 2$$
$$b^2 (c+a)=4$$
$$c^2 (a+b)= 10$$
The question wants me to solve for all the possible values of the product abc.
What I have tried so far:
I have tried eliminating c and b and making equation in a but it gives a very high degree equation in a.
Futher I have tried substracting respective equations to get ab+bc+ca but that is getting me nowhere. Kindly help.
Edit: I was able to solve this as soon as I posted it here !

most basic strategy is solve first for b, plug it in to second. solve that for c, then plug that in the third. thers only one letter in that equation now

Multiply the equations and let $x=abc$.  You'll get
$$x^2(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=80.$$
Expand $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ to get
$$x^2(2x+2+4+10)=80.$$

As soon as I posted the question here. I was able to solve!
equating the values of ab+bc+ca, we get
c= 4b-3a
Substituting this equation 1 and 2,
We can solve for b/a
Using which we can solve for c/a
Then it's trivial to solve for individual values.
